# How to transpose 3 level of rows to be in separated column in python?

Tags: python, transpose

I have this table where one of the columns has 3 levels and I want to transpose each level to be in 3 separated columns.

It only has 3 levels, but the third level is various (not constantly have 2 values, it could have more than that or it might also have 2 levels only)

```
tag      type         progress setting ea
10-T   Mineral            
        bottom             2
         Girder 1          1
         Girder 2          1
        Up                 5
         shell 1           2
         shell 2           3
40-T   Fresh            
         Roof              7,5
          Wind 1           2
          Wind 2           5,5
         Up                 6
```

The first column, which is `tag` is existed only in one row and I want the string to also exist in another row once the table is transposed.

In the case where the column has only 2 levels, then the `detail` column is filled with the same value as the `desc` column.

The expected table is like below:

```
tag      type        desc     detail      progress setting ea
10-T   Mineral       bottom   Girder 1         1
10-T   Mineral       bottom   Girder 2         1
10-T   Mineral       up       Shell 1          2
10-T   Mineral       up       Shell 2          3
40-T   Fresh         Roof     Wind 1           2
40-T   Fresh         Roof     Wind 2           5,5
40-T   Fresh         Up       Up               6
```

How should I use the `df.transpose` to get my expected table?

Answer (score 1):

No straightforward command will give you the result you are seeking for because the dependent task numbers are given as a comma delimited list within the progress column. You have to first get rid of the hierarchical index, then loop through all the rows and duplicate any row with more that one number in the progress column.